# About remove elements inside iframe

Tags: jquery

How to remove or hide contents or elements of website inside
 **iframe** in **jquery**?

Comment: Google is a better place to ask such a questions

Comment: ya but didnt get any right code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Remove all contents in iframe

```
   $("iframe").children().remove();
```

- Hide all contents in iframe

```
   $("iframe").children().hide();
```